# Access SQLite datatabase remotely through java app

Tags: java, sqlite, java-web-start

Im working with a SQLite database right now, and I've made a javaFX application (I will call it the client) that allows me to work with it, but I need to work with it remotely as well. From what I've read SQLite does not support remote acces,  so I have 2 choices:

1. Creating another application in the server that receives input from the client through a socket, and it modifies the SQLite database. (The problem with this, is that the server is a webserver and I dont have SSH access, so I can upload the server side application on the server, but I cant start it...)
2. (I dont know if this works) Create a java application that runs on the server, and you load it through a browser such as chrome or firefox. From what I've seen java webstart allows you that, but I don't if the app runs on the server or on your computer (meaning that you won't have acces to the SQLite database as well).

If someone here has some knowledge on this pls share, I need to know if I can make this work, and if not, what other options I have.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think SQLite is designed for that. If you use SQLite because it's small and easy, why don't you try JavaDB (derby), it is included in your JDK distribution and you can use it embedded in your app or as a database server (not both of course).

Comment: nah, it has to be SQLite, otherwise I would have looked up some other solution :/
thanks anyway.